# How to preallocate objects for thread pooled server?

Tags: java, ssl, threadpool, bouncycastle, tls-psk

In [a simple test case](https://github.com/afarber/jetty-newbie/tree/master/TlsPskServer2/src/main/java/de/afarber/tlspskserver2) I have implemented a thread pooled server accepting up to 10 simultaneous incoming TLS PSK connections at port 12345 and printing decrypted data at standard output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket server  = new ServerSocket(12345);
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    while (true) {
        Socket socket = server.accept();
        pool.execute(new MyRunnable(socket));
    }
}
```

Here is the `Runnable` implementation used by the threads:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        SecureRandom random      = new SecureRandom();       // How to preallocate?
        BufferedInputStream bis  = new BufferedInputStream(mSocket.getInputStream());
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(mSocket.getOutputStream());
        TlsServerProtocol proto  = new TlsServerProtocol(bis, bos, random);
        MockPSKTlsServer server  = new MockPSKTlsServer();   // How to preallocate?
        proto.accept(server);
        Streams.pipeAll(proto.getInputStream(), System.out);
        proto.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.print(e);
    }
}
```

How to preallocate the `SecureRandom` and `MockPSKTlsServer` objects used by the `Runnable`?

I.e. how to create 10 of both objects in the `main()` and then just reuse them in the `run()`?

Comment: which version of Java do you use?

Comment: I am using [Java SE 1.8](https://github.com/afarber/jetty-newbie/blob/master/TlsPskServer2/pom.xml) on Windows and Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case I would use a [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) for each class (`SecureRandom` and `MockPSKTlsServer`), to have one dedicated instance of `SecureRandom` and `MockPSKTlsServer` for each thread of your connection pool and reuse them when the threads will have to execute the same type of task but with different input `Socket`, something like:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<SecureRandom> random = ThreadLocal.withInitial(
    SecureRandom::new
);
private static final ThreadLocal<MockPSKTlsServer> server = ThreadLocal.withInitial(
    MockPSKTlsServer::new
);

...
public void run() {
    try (BufferedInputStream bis  = new BufferedInputStream(mSocket.getInputStream());
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(mSocket.getOutputStream());
        TlsServerProtocol proto  = new TlsServerProtocol(bis, bos, random.get())) {
        // Calling server.get() will get the instance dedicated to the current
        // thread, if no instance exists so far for this thread
        // new MockPSKTlsServer() will automatically be called then
        // affected to this thread for subsequent get's calls
        proto.accept(server.get());
        ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.print(e);
    }
}
```

**NB:** Use the [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to automatically close your input/output streams.

Comment: If I make the `random` and `server` variables **static** in [MyRunnable.java](https://github.com/afarber/jetty-newbie/tree/master/TlsPskServer2/src/main/java/de/afarber/tlspskserver2) and have 10 instances of that class - won't they be used by all 10 instances? I am curious why do you suggest **static** here? Because what I need is 10 pre-allocated `SecureRandom` and `MockPSKTlsServer` instances for each thread in my pool...

Comment: No it must be **static** otherwise your `ThreadLocal` would be useless. You should read the javadoc about a `ThreadLocal`, in a nutshell a `ThreadLocal` is used to scope an instance of a given class to a `Thread`, in other words what thread 1 will get from the `ThreadLocal`  will be different from what thread 2 will get. So if you have 10 threads calling `get()` on the `ThreadLocal`, the `ThreadLocal` will actually manage 10 instances of your class (one per thread).

Answer (score 2):

Normally I would use a `ThreadLocal<>` and use a lightweight `Pool<T>` class to hold and provide the instances.

I don't think there is a `Pool<T>` out of the box, but this is trivially constructed.

The only consideration with `ThreadLocal<>` is you have to ensure that you release back to the `Pool<>` correctly. So if you are thinking of communicating this to another thread, a better approach may be a static pool that is shared, but either with locking (if you don't care too much about performance) or concurrent container if you do..

Having said that: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/

Comment: Actually I don't communicate with other threads. I read incoming data, decrypt it and close the socket. In the long term I would like to forward the decrypted data to an embedded Jetty (which can't [TLS PSK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS-PSK)) through another socket. I.e. I am trying to program a thread-pooled "reverse proxy" for Jetty.

Comment: Well, you don't need a pool then, looks like you only need a single instance - in this case - ignore the stuff about pool and stick it in a `ThreadLocal<>` directly..